# grouping data frame within the list

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a unique issue that I am trying to solve.

I have a data table that contains few different types of information in it.
Example bellow.

```
ID|inpSeq|Act |User |Representing
--|----- |----|---- |-----
1 | 123  | s  | ABC | NA
1 | 124  | s  | ABC | NA
1 | 125  | c  | ABC | x1
1 | 126  | c  | XYZ | x2
1 | 127  | d  | ABC | x2
```

What I am trying to do is to organize the data so that view how "User" relates to "Repres"

In other words, I am looking to create following output

```
ID|Act   |User|....
--|------|----|----|----
1 | sscd | ABC| x1 | x2.....
1 |  c   | XYZ| x2.....
```

So as you can see the original table is compacted into "User" centric view and the "Act" now contains all the activity that User performed on single ID.

Additionally, one I have this activity sorted out, I would need to (dynamically, if different) show on who's behalf they performed the activity.  This is represented by x1, x2..... meaning that this can grow depending on how may unique "Representing" parties there are for each ID/Act/User combinations.

An important thing to note is that "s" values in Act field will always have NA in Representing filed. So in those NA do not need to be included in the transformed view.

Now thus far I was able to get the `ID|Act|User` part of the code figured out by using following code

```
aggregate(Act~ID+User, paste, collapse="", data=df)
```

But I need to figure out how to do the rest. That is where I need all of your help.

P.S. "inpSeq" field is a just unique numeric field that is created sequentially by an outside application and it allows for ordering of activities in correct sequential order.

Comment: You may want to consider the `nest` function in `tidyr` which allows for lists of values in single cells of a data frame. See: https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data as a data frame `df`, you can use `dplyr` with the `spread` function from `tidyr` to get what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f <- function(x) { paste(na.omit(x), collapse="") }         ## 1.

result <- df %>% spread(Representing, Representing) %>%     ## 2.
                 select(-inpSeq, -`<NA>`) %>%               ## 3.
                 group_by(ID, User) %>%                     ## 4.
                 summarise_each(funs(f)))
```

Notes:

1. We define a function `f` that collapses the vector of characters to a single string and omits `NA`s in the process.
2. The first argument to `spread` is the column name for the *keys* and the second argument is the column name for the *values*. The `spread` function spreads the the *values* into multiple columns. These additional columns are named by the *keys*. Here, we spread the rows of `Representing` into multiple columns named after the rows of `Representing`. The result of just that command on your data gives:

   ```
   ##  ID inpSeq Act User   x1   x2 <NA>
   ##1  1    123   s  ABC <NA> <NA> <NA>
   ##2  1    124   s  ABC <NA> <NA> <NA>
   ##3  1    125   c  ABC   x1 <NA> <NA>
   ##4  1    126   c  XYZ <NA>   x2 <NA>
   ##5  1    127   d  ABC <NA>   x2 <NA>
   ```

   Note that there are now three additional columns named `x1`, `x2`, and `<NA>` replacing the original `Representing` column.
3. From this result, we use `select` to omit the columns `inpSeq` and `<NA>`.
4. We then `group_by` `ID` and `User` and `summaries_each` of the remaining columns using the function `f` that we defined.

The result is:

```
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
##Groups: ID [?]

##     ID   User   Act    x1    x2
##  <int> <fctr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
##1     1    ABC  sscd    x1    x2
##2     1    XYZ     c          x2
```